# Get content from <strong> tags

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to collect the contents from all the `strong` tag in the `div id='content'` and fill `[ul id='loop']` with them

Before:

```
 <div id='content'>
     this <strong>is</strong> a <strong>long</strong> content
 </div>

 <ul id='loop'>

 </ul>
```

After:

```
<div id='content'>
    this <strong>is</strong> a <strong>long</strong> content
</div>

<ul id='loop'>
   <li>is</li>
   <li>long</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can iterate through all strong elements and add its text to ul, see below code

```js
$(function(){
   $('#content strong').each(function(){ // get all strong from content
     $('#loop').append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>'); // create li with text
   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'>this <strong>is</strong> a <strong>long</strong> content</div>

    <ul id='loop'>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `map` the `strong` elements to `li` elements and then `appendTo` the `ul` element.

```js
$('#content strong').map(function () {
    return $('<li>').text($(this).text()).get();
}).appendTo('#loop');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'>this <strong>is</strong> a <strong>long</strong> content</div>
<ul id='loop'>
</ul>
```

Make sure to put the code near the end of the `body` tag if it has to execute immediately or else wrap it in `$(function () { .... })`

Comment: this answer is also the most efficient. only appends once so DOM parsers will have less weight

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery to do this - just straight js. Using querySelectorAll to get the elements. Then iterate over that list to create the li's for the #loop list.

```js
var strongElements = document.querySelectorAll('#content strong');

var loopStr = '';

strongElements.forEach(function(element) {
  loopStr += '<li>' + element.innerText + '</li>';
})

document.querySelector('#loop').innerHTML = loopStr
```

```html
<div id='content'>this <strong>is</strong> a <strong>long</strong> content</div>

<ul id='loop'></ul>
```

Comment: @LGSon - thanks for the advice - I have removed the chained queries and replaced with a single selector - should have done that first. Thanks.

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("strong")